# What is the cheapest PC compatible with Oculus Rift?

Tags: gaming, pc, vr-headset

I just got an Oculus Rift, and now I need a PC to use it with.  My question is, what is the cheapest available PC that I can use an Oculus Rift with?

**Note**: I don't want to have to build a PC, I want something I can just buy and use.

The cheapest I've found is [this Cyberpower PC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NBL8BER), which is $720.  Does anyone know if there's anything cheaper?

EDIT: I found a cheaper one, [another Cyberpower PC](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/cyberpowerpc-gamer-ultra-vr-desktop-amd-fx-series-8gb-memory-amd-radeon-rx-470-1tb-hard-drive/5655811.p?skuId=5655811) for $650.  Is there anything cheaper than that?

EDIT 2: I ultimately went with the $720 Cyberpower PC I linked to above.  So my question is now moot.  But I'll leave it up for the benefit of others.

Comment: I've found Cyberpower PC to not have very good value for the computers they sell.

Comment: I know that you don't want to build your own, but something like [this](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/zcnfZ8) costs 716usd and has a much better cpu, gpu and ram than both of the machines you linked. [This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38236071#38236071) disclaimer applies, though.

Comment: @BennettYeo I don't really want "good value", I just want to be able to use my Oculus Rift.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan if you mention cheapest, don't you mean good value -> lowest price for the performance? I think you don't want to pay 50 dollar more for a similar pc

Comment: @Houbie No, I don't mean that.  I just want to be able to use my Oculus Rift for the least possible amount of money.  I don't really care about "good value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by saying that, as a person who had little knowledge about building a computer, but ended up doing exactly that, building is definitely the route i would take when building a Virtual Reality capable machine.

Couple of reasons for this:

- You get exponentially more power for your money.
- I personally cannot bear to spend more than necessary, and market pre-built gaming computers generally have a large markup.

With that out of the way, Oculus actually have a recommended list of computers [here on their site](https://www.oculus.com/oculus-ready-pcs/). One that sticks out to me in the kind of price range you are mentioning above is the [Lenovo IdeaCentre Y700](http://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/ideacentre/y700/ideacentre-Y700-34ISH/p/99IC9Y70219).

The first in the range of these models actually starts at $649, which should have plenty enough power to run VR games.

There is actually a reason why I would recommend this over your $650 Cyberpower PC, (some people are not going to like this), but it has a NVidia GPU. In my experience, most (not all) VR experiences run much better on NVidia cards, but don't hold me to that as I have no solid or documented proof, I have tried both and I personally preferred the NVidia experience overall.

Another point to mention is that this computer sports an Intel processor, but that AMD vs Intel is a very contentious topic, and I don't feel it is my place to start an argument on that. (I recommend Intel by the way :p)

I threw together a price on PCPartPicker, but for the ease of purchase and performance, I couldn't recommend the Y700 more, it seems like a really good deal.

Comment: I ultimately bought the $720 Cyberpower PC ([this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NBL8BER)), so my question is now moot.  But just so the bounty doesn't go to waste, I'm awarding it to you.